# Unable to display all data from mysql json column

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am retrieving a single row of data from several joined tabled using first(), this includes a json column called properties. I am able to display all the non json data as expected in my blade template.

However for the json column called properties I am pulling my hair out, spend endless hours googling, looking on her but to no avail.

Appreciate if someone could point out the blindingly obvious (as I'm sure it will be)

I have tried also and reached a point where I can access anything in the root of the object but nothing that is nested.

**So pretty version of dd($quote->properties) returns;**

```
"{
  "mode": 1,
  "service": 1,
  "rates": {
    "DAP": 825.22
  },
  "detail": {
    "weights": {
      "actual": 111.00,
      "volume": 0,
      "chargeable": 111.00
    }
  }
}"
```

*I Appreciate the leading and trailing "s are only added to render in the browser and don't exist in the actual column.*

**Using** `{{ json_decode($quote->properties,true)['mode'] }}`

**Result** = 1 which is as desired output.

**However** `{{ json_decode($quote->properties,true)['rates']['DAP'] }}`

**Result** = Undefined index: DAP

**Desired** = 825.22

**{{ var_dump(json_decode($quote->properties,true)) }}**

```
    array (size=4)
      'mode' => int 1
      'service' => int 1
      'rates' => 
        array (size=1)
          'DAP' => float 825.22
      'detail' => 
        array (size=1)
          'weights' => 
            array (size=3)
              'actual' => string '111.00' (length=6)
              'volume' => int 0
              'chargeable' => string '111.00' (length=6)
```

Comment: I only see `'DAP'` in your json, I don't see `'DDU'`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated ticket to correct as that was a typo but the result is the same.

Comment: maybe some instances of that "type" don't have that property DAP set... and that's why you see the error in a specific case. By the way.. it would be helpful for you to dump the json_decode for all the occurrencies and see with your own eyes why and when [rates][dap] addressing doesn't have success

Comment: You can try `{{ json_decode($quote->properties,true)['rates']['DAP'] ?? 'DAP not set' }}`

Comment: @DiegoDeVita edited posted to include var_dump

Comment: @GTCrais thanks its now working... I have no idea why {{ json_decode($quote->properties,true)['rates']['DAP'] }} is now working??

Comment: `??` aka null coalesce operator returns the first operand (i.e. the left part) if it exists, otherwise it returns the second (i.e. the right part). In other words, if `['rates']['DAP']` isn't set, it will return `'DAP not set'` instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I have no idea why working....

Perhaps I had a typo and re-adding fixed or cleared view cache??

Thank you all for responding.